# Laravel - How to dynamically resolve an instance of a model that has different Namespace?

Tags: laravel

## tldr:

How do you dynamically get an instance of a model just by its DB table name?

**What you get from the request:**

- ID of the model
- table name of the model **(it varies all the time!)**

**What you don't know:**

- Namespace of the model

---

## Longer explanation:

I have a reporting system, that users can use to report something. For each reporting, the ID and the table name is sent.

Until now, every model was under the Namespace `App\*`. However, since my project is too big, I needed to split some code into `Modules\*`

Here is an example, how the report is saved in the database:

**Example:**

Request contains rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'required|string',
        'type' => 'required|in:users,comments,offer_reviews, ......',
        'reason' => 'required|string',
        'meta' => 'nullable|array',
        'meta.*' => 'string|max:300'
    ];
}
```

In the database, we save the data into :

```
id  reportable_type            ...
1   App\User                   ...
4   Modules\Review\OfferReview ...
```

How would you create an instance of a model dynamically, when you just know the database table name for example `offer_reviews`?

There is one solution that jumps to my mind, however, I'm not sure if it adds more security issues. What is if the user sends the full namespace + class name? With that, I know directly where to resolve an instance.

## Have a look what I'm doing right now

#### (before I changed to modules)

//In my controller

```
class ReportController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Stores the report in DB.
     */
    public function store(StoreReportRequest $request)
    {
        $model = $request->getModel();

        $model->report([
            'reason' => $request->reason,
            'meta' => $request->meta
        ], auth()->user());

        return response()->json(['status' => 'Submitted'], 201);
    }
}
```

//in StoreReportRequest

```
/**
 * Gets the Model dynamically.
 * If not found we throw an error
 * @return \App\Model
 */
public function getModel()
{
    return get_model($this->type)
                ->findOrFail(\Hashids::decode($this->id)[0]);
}
```

//in Helpers

```
/**
 * Gets me the model of a table name.
 * @param  String $table Has to be the name of a table of Database
 * @return Eloquent       The model itself
 */
function get_model($table)
{
    if (Schema::hasTable(strtolower($table))) {
        return resolve('App\\' . Str::studly(Str::singular($table)));
    }
    throw new TableNotFound;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using Polymorphic Relationships (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) ?

Comment: you cannot create the instance of a model dynamically except you wish to create a file named with the model instance but you can create table dynamically.

Comment: @ChinLeung I think you didn't understand me correctly. It's an ajax request to the server. I don't care about the polymorphic relationship. I just need to resolve a model from the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better solution, but here you go. My code is looking for a method with namespace when it's not found we are using `App\` as the namespace.

Maybe this code helps someone :)

```
class StoreReportRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'required|string',
            'type' => 'required|in:mc_messages,profile_tweets,food,users,comments,offer_reviews,user_reviews',
            'reason' => 'required|string',
            'meta' => 'nullable|array',
            'meta.*' => 'string|max:300'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the Model dynamically.
     * If not found we throw an error
     * @return \App\Model
     */
    public function getModel()
    {
        $namespace = $this->getNamespace();

        return $this->resolveModel($namespace);
    }

    protected function getNamespace(): string
    {
        $method = $this->typeToMethod();

        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            return $this->$method();
        }
        return 'App\\';
    }

    protected function typeToMethod(): string
    {
        return  'get' . \Str::studly(\Str::singular($this->type)) . 'Namespace';
    }

    protected function resolveModel(string $namespace)
    {
        return get_model($this->type, $namespace)
            ->findOrFail(\Hashids::decode($this->id)[0]);
    }

    protected function getOfferReviewNamespace(): string
    {
        return 'Modules\Review\Entities\\';
    }

    protected function getUserReviewNamespace(): string
    {
        return 'Modules\Review\Entities\\';
    }
}
```